# How to implement the Decorator Design pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, decorator

Could anybody help me to implement the Decorator design pattern in javascript. I have a TankBase entity:

```
TankBase = function (x, y, width, height, direction, imageOptions) {
    TankBase.base.call(this, x, y, width, height, imageOptions);
    this.speed = 250;
    this.direction = direction;
    this.render = function (drawEngine) {
        drawEngine.render();
    };
    ...
}
```

I want to add a new functionality using the Decorator pattern. For example, I want to modify the render() function and draw a health indicator under a tank:

```
var TankHealthDecorator = function (tank) {
    var _tank = tank;
    this.render = function (drawEngine) {
        // draw a health indicator
        ...
        _tank.render(drawEngine);
    };
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var tank = new TankHealthDecorator(new HeavyTank());
```

where HeavyTank inherits TankBase.

How should I modify TankHealthDecorator() to use it like a wrapper for a tank instance?

**EDIT:**

Thank you, Paul, for a great article:

> I would start here: addyosmani.com/blog/decorator-pattern Good write
>   up. – Paul

Comment: Why exactly do you need `this` to equal `tank`?

Comment: I would start here: http://addyosmani.com/blog/decorator-pattern/ Good write up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally I think what you have is pretty close. I'd store off the original render function, assign a new one, and then simply apply it from within the decorated one. I also don't see a need to create the decorator as an object, but that's probably more of a preference thing.

```
var DrawEngine = { render: function() {
    console.log('render');
} };

var TankBase = function (x, y, width, height, direction, imageOptions) {
    this.speed = 250;
    this.direction = direction;
    this.render = function (drawEngine) {
        drawEngine.render();
    };
};

var HeavyTank = function() {
    TankBase.apply(this, arguments);
    this.render = function() {
        console.log('heavyTank Render');
    }
}

function DecorateTankWithHealthIndicator (tank) {
    var oRender = tank.render;
    tank.render = function (drawEngine) {
        console.log('draw a health indicator');
        oRender.apply(tank, arguments);
    };
};

var btank = new TankBase();
var htank = new HeavyTank();
btank.render(DrawEngine);
htank.render(DrawEngine);
DecorateTankWithHealthIndicator(btank);
DecorateTankWithHealthIndicator(htank);
btank.render(DrawEngine);
htank.render(DrawEngine);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following approach a tankBase object gets passed to the tankHealth function. The tankBase object gets modified within the tankHealth function, saving the tankBase object in the var `that`. After the modification `that` gets returned as the modified tankBase object.

```
var TankBase = function () {
        this.render = function () {
            console.log('tankBase')
        };
    }

var TankHealthDecorator = function (tank) {
    var that = tank;

    that.render = function() {
        console.log('tankHealth')
    };

    return that;
}

window.onload = function(){
    var tankBase = new TankBase();
    var testHealth = new TankHealthDecorator(new TankBase());

    tankBase.render();     // tank base
    testHealth.render();   // tank health
};
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to call tank.render() method inside that.render(). For example, that.render = function() {
        console.log('tankHealth'); tank.render();
    };

And this leads to an infinite loop.

Comment: The "that" keyword in your example prevents problems when you forget the "new" keyword before TankHealthDecorator. This is not the Decorator pattern, but anyway THANKS!!!

Comment: You may also have a look at [this](http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html) article. It explains inheritance and the call of ancestor methods.

Answer (score 0):

## The Decorator Pattern

Here is a rough implementation of the **Decorator Pattern** -- AKA: ***Wrapper***:

#### Background:

The Decorator Pattern is typically used to *add additional responsibilities* to an object dynamically by *forwarding requests* onto its accepted Component, **and|or** decouple *Deep Inheritance Hierarchies* to be *Compositive* in *Type* (not to be confused with the *Composite Pattern* -- which is *Compositive* in *Hierarchy* -- using a *Component-Leaf* structure to allow synonymous requests across a uniform, fractal topology [treating parents & children equally]).

```
function AbstractComponent(){
    this.draw = function(){
        console.log('@AbstractComponent | #draw');
    };
}

function AbstractDecorator(){
    AbstractComponent.call(this);  // Inherit AbstractComponent Interface
    this.notify = function(){
        console.log('@AbstractDecorator | #notify');
    };
}

function ConcreteComponent(options){
    AbstractComponent.call(this);  // Inherit AbstractComponent Interface
    this.fill = function(){
        console.log('@ConcreteComponent | #fill');
    };
}

function ConcreteDecorator(Component){
    AbstractDecorator.call(this);  // Inherit AbstractDecorator Interface
    function PrivateResponsibility(){
        console.log('@ConcreteDecorator | #PrivateResponsibility');
    }
    this.additionalResponsibility = function(){
        console.log('@ConcreteDecorator | #additionalResponsibility');
    };
    this.draw = function(){
        console.log('@ConcreteDecorator | #draw-Component.draw');
        // ... additional logic
        PrivateResponsibility();
        Component.draw();
    };
    this.fill = function(){
        console.log('@ConcreteDecorator | #fill-Component.fill');
        Component.fill();
    };
}

var concreteComponent = new ConcreteComponent();
concreteComponent = new ConcreteDecorator(concreteComponent);  // use same variable name as to allow client code to remain the same

//CLIENT CODE
concreteComponent.draw();
concreteComponent.fill();
concreteComponent.notify();
concreteComponent.additionalResponsibility();
```

Answer (score -1):

Following is my understanding about function(object) decoration

```
 function api_decorator(some_data){
     return function decorator(func){
        return function new_function(args){
         /* do somethinfg with data before and after func */
         console.log("I'm code before with data: "+some_data);
         func(args);
         console.log("I'm code after");
    }
  }
}

function somefunc(data){
    console.log("Hi, I'm func "+data);
}

somefunc("without decoration")
/* injecting somefunc in decorator api */
somefunc=api_decorator("data needed for api")(somefunc)
/* calling decorated with api somefunc */
somefunc("with decoration")
```

Comment: The Decorator Pattern is also known as a "Wrapper"...
...
This IS a decorative pattern, known as the Function-Curry Pattern -- however, this is not THE Decorator Pattern. NO DOWN-VOTE because of its demonstration of DECORATING a function -- or, "Wrapping" a Logic-Set.

Comment: decorator is decorative term ninja